# Rails: how to get datetime from model in original timezone (different entries = different timezones)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

Given model which i want to create with `"starts_at"=>"2016-02-04T14:30:00.000+01:00"`

This entry stored in postgres, `starts_at` should keep timezone - this is important to keep it as it is and display in HTML **exactly** this time - 14:30.
Meaning for business: user saves his time from London. Admin check entry from Australia and he should speak to user in **user's timezone**

At same time I need server to be able to properly understand which time it is, so I can "select entries within 1 hour form now"

Rails give:

```
[28] pry(main)> entry.starts_at
=> 2016-02-04 13:30:00 UTC
[17] pry(main)> entry.attributes_before_type_cast["starts_at"]
=> "2016-02-04 13:30:00+00"
```

I suppose that postgress throw away timezone, though I tried type:

```
  t.change :starts_at, 'timestamp with time zone'
```

How to store/retrieve field in proper timezone, which is stored in postgress.
It can be any timezone for different entries, code doesn't know which entry has which time zone, so we **can't use in_time_zone** (Unless I will store timezone in separate field, which seems too dummy)

Is there something like `do_not_touch_timezones_for :starts_at` or `starts_at.original_timezone` or global config.

Tried `self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:starts_at, :ends_at]` - has no any effect

Answer (score 1):

Is there any issues with [Time#`parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse)? It seems to return the time you want:

```
Time.parse("2016-02-04T14:30:00.000+01:00")
#=> 2016-02-04 14:30:00 +0100
```

Comment: That would be solution, if I would keep date as string in database. (Which I actually do now :) Though is there solution for `:datetime` columns?